IntelliJ "No candidates found for method call" error
Trying to import Java Template Engine (JTE) into IntelliJ. It doesn't seem to recognise the import because when I tried to reference JavalinJte.init(); it said no candidates found for method call.
I have tried deleting the .idea, rebuilding the package, reloading Maven, starting a new project. Code below:
import io.javalin.rendering.template.JavalinJte;
JavalinJte.init();
It works fine in Eclipse so this seems to be IDE specific.

I'm not sure how you add that library to your project.
I'd use Maven:
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/gg.jte/jte -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>gg.jte</groupId>
    <artifactId>jte</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.9</version>
</dependency>


Yes, that's in my pom already

Have you downloaded the libraries?  Do they appear in IntelliJ?  The pom.xml is necessary, but not sufficient.  You need to ask Maven to download them.  Did you do that yet?

I'm not sure, when I hover over the dependencies they seem to appear, how do I know if they're downloaded?

"Seem to appear" - you should see them in the left panel under External Libraries.   Run Maven and check.

Would it be possible for you to kindly provide a minimal sample project for me to reproduce the issue while ensuring that your sensitive code is not included? You can put it on Google Drive or GitHub. BWT, which version of IDEA you are using?

Or, better yet, just post the code here.
